# Reusing a computed column in insert statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to insert 4 columns into a table where the fourth is the sum of second and third. 
The logical equivalent of the desired output is as follows but it is not syntactically correct.
The main point is that calculation of MISCPRICE is complicated and i want to use that result to find total.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, BASEPRICE, MISCPRICE, TOTAL)
SELECT TABLE2.ID, TABLE2.BASEPRICE,
       (SELECT (SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID)
               + TABLE4.TAX + TABLE4.MISC
        FROM TABLE4
        WHERE TABLE4.ID = TABLE2.ID), ?????
FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE2.ID NOT IN             
    (SELECT TABLE1.ID
     FROM TABLE1)

--ONLY INSERTING WHEN THE ID IS NOT ALREADY PRESENT IN THE TABLE
```

So to find the total I could do something like the following, but that meanrepeating the whole calculation of MISCPRICE which is a performance overhead and messy to look at too.

```
TABLE2.BASEPRICE
    +
(SELECT (SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID)
          + TABLE4.TAX + TABLE4.MISC
 FROM TABLE4
 WHERE TABLE4.ID = TABLE2.ID)
```

I tried using (BASEPRICE + MISCPRICE) for total but it says

> invalid column name "BASEPRICE"

Is there any way to reuse the calculated column MISPRICE to find the total while inserting?

I did solve this using a temp table and computing row-wise using variables. But I wanted to avoid that when possible.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  If the fourth column is always the sum of the other two, why not use a trigger, view, or computed column?

Comment: I am using MS SQL server. Corrected tags

Comment: Version of SQL-Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping it in another Select although I agree with @GordonLinoff in the comments that the ideal solution is not to store the value at all, in this way.  Exact systax may vary slightly for your DB system.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(ID, BASEPRICE, MISCPRICE, TOTAL)
 SELECT ID, BASEPRICE, MISCPRICE, BASEPRICE + MISCPRICE FROM (
  SELECT TABLE2.ID, TABLE2.BASEPRICE,
   (SELECT (SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID)
           + TABLE4.TAX + TABLE4.MISC
    FROM TABLE4
    WHERE TABLE4.ID = TABLE2.ID) AS MISCPRICE
 FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.ID NOT IN             
 (SELECT TABLE1.ID
  FROM TABLE1.ID)) TEMP_VIEW
```

Comment: Thanks. I now understand how to use a view for this purpose. But in the end I went with a computed column as @GordonLinoff suggested as i found it also served my purpose as I also seemed to need it to apply to updates and since I had the liberty to change the Table design